# Passing refs on React Native with TypeScript: (property) React.MutableRefObject<null>.current: null Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, react-native-textinput

I have several fields on a React Native form and I would like that the focus jump from one to the next one each time the user validate the field with the virtual keyboard.

I came up with something like that:

```
        <NamedTextInput
          name={'email'}
          ref={emailRef}
          ...
          onSubmitEditing={() => passwordRef.current.focus()}
        />
        
        <NamedTextInput
          name={'password'}
          ref={passwordRef}
          ...
        />
```

On current I get a TypeScript error:

```
(property) React.MutableRefObject<null>.current: null
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
```

I tried to add ! and ? marks but it ends into:

```
Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

Any idea to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I got this one. I forgot the typing in the useRef declaration:

```
const passwordRef = useRef<TextInput>(null)
```

Then I can add a ! mark or check the existence the current ref without getting the "never" error:

```
onSubmitEditing={() => (passwordRef.current && passwordRef.current.focus())}
```